# How do I login to applications with a Google account that uses 2-Step Verification?

Tags: login, verification, windows-live-writer, google-authenticator

I need to use my Google account to login to places like Windows Live Writer.  Sometimes the second step in the 2-Step Verification process gets in the way, causing a Password and Email combination error. How can I get around that without temporarily disabling 2-Step Verification?

Answer (score 3):

You can use an application-specific password.

[Google Support: Sign in using application-specific password](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/1173270)

> The codes that you’ll get with 2-step verification don’t work with all applications. There are a few applications that use information from your Google Account that require application-specific passwords (ASPs).
>   Using application-specific passwords
>
> Examples of devices and applications that use ASPs include: Email clients such as Outlook, Apple Mail and Thunderbird, and Gmail and Google Calendar on your phone. Below are two examples of what you might see when using an application that requires an ASP.

Essentially, this lets you sign into your Google Account with a one-time password instead of 2-step authentication.